# MySql Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, access-denied

I have a command line problem accessing mysql.

```
Entering /usr/syno/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -pxxxx -hlocalhost mediawiki
```

gives me

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I, however, omit the password,

```
/usr/syno/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost mediawiki
```

I'm prompted for a password and may log in.

What do I do wrong in the first command line?

MySql version: 5.1.49

`OS: Linux DiskStation 2.6.32.12 #2661 Mon Nov 12 23:09:58 CST 2012 armv5tel GNU/Linux (Synology NAS)`

Mikael

Comment: I'm going to assume that you have some sort of special character in your password. `$` causes the most problems, so I'll use it as an example. Wrap the argument in single quotes thusly `'-ppa$$word'` and if that doesn't work start escaping things with \.

Comment: Thank you, wrapping the password part in single quotes made it work.