# OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, scrapy, mysql-error-1045

I use Scrapy and wnat to insert the Data in my database.

in my database.py i have

```
def __init__(self, host='', user='', password='', database=''):
    self.__host     = 'localhost'
    self.__user     = 'root'
    self.__password = 'mypass'
    self.__database = 'drive'
## End def __init__

def __open(self):
    try:
cnx = MySQLdb.connect(self.__host, self.__user, self.__password, self.__database, port="3308")
self.__connection = cnx
self.__session    = cnx.cursor()
```

except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print "\033[31mError %d: %s\033[0m" % (e.args[0],e.args[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161581/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes))

and in manager when i want to connect to mysql with

```
    self.mysql = MysqlPython(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db)
    self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

i have this error:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161581/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382219/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-ye) but i have already the same eror and i can' access to my database

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are correctly setting the root password, but remember you can reset the password.

First things first.

Stop mysql server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Log in as root and stop the mysql daemon. Now lets start up the mysql daemon and skip the grant tables which store the passwords.

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

You should see mysqld start up successfully. If not, well you have bigger issues. Now you should be able to connect to mysql without a password.

```
mysql -u root mysql

update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;

exit;
```

Comment: I added a photo to my question, please check it out

Comment: i got this error: mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
2016-05-30T15:22:14.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/pc-2.home.err'.
2016-05-30T15:22:14.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: /usr/local/var/mysql/pc-2.home.err: Permission denied
rm: /tmp/mysql.sock: Permission denied
/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe: line 169

Comment: You've launched with sudo?

Comment: with sudo i have this error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot comment that you need to stop mysql server "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop" .  I edited my solution because there are code errors. Now is correct

Comment: i don't have /etc/init.d/mysql, but when i try to install mysql by brew install mysql i have Warning: mysql-5.7.12 already installed

Comment: find your mysql installed location or mysql server management and stop server. I don't know the location in other OS. What is your OS?

Comment: el capitain 10.11.3

Comment: i can do all this in phpmyadmin? i change the password but i have the same eror

Comment: For mysql pre 5.7 _sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop_ for post 5.7 _sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist_ in my os x El capitan there are a mysql management and I can stop server from this

Comment: i tried the second one and i have this : /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: Check your System preferences [link]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/images/mac-installer-preference-pane-location.png and select MySQL Preference Panel to stop server [link]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/images/mac-installer-preference-pane-usage.png

Comment: thanks, but i have this error mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--u' when i type mysql --u root mysql

Comment: Sorry is mysql -u root mysql

Answer (score 2):

> had same issue ,changed connector and it worked for me, but first install the module

**$ pip install mysql-connector-python**

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='psw', host='127.0.0.1', database='db')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Grant Option at the end:

```
GRANT all privileges on dbx.* to 'x'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'x' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```